# problem with jquery loading plugin on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I' using the jquery loading plugin :

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/loading

To display a "please wait..." message fixed at the top of the browser page when an ajax request is being processed. This message is fixed at the top (like the messages at the top of the stackoverflow site), so are there even if the window is scrolled.

It works more or less fine except on IE it only displays when the browser window is not scrolled down (ie. the viewport is at 0,0). If the page is scrolled a bit it doesn't display (it does actually display but at the top of the page, if you scroll up you can see it).

Anybody come across a solution ? I tried posting on the jquery bugs board but no reply for months.

Alternatively, could you recommend an alternative solution or plugin to use that doesn't have this problem ?

Comment: I see the same problem in IE8: http://jquery-values.googlecode.com/svn/other/loading/jquery.loading.htm - so it looks like a bug in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could "hack" the plugin so it uses "position: fixed" instead of "position: absolute"